# Vertex expander bounded

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, spectral-graph-theory, matching-theory

> Let $G_1$, $G_2$, . . . be a family of ε-vertex expanders on $n_1$, $n_2$, . . . vertices. Show that there is a constant c such that eventually the diameter of $G_j$ is bounded from above by c · log($n_j$).

The definition of  ε-vertex expanders I am using is as following: a sequence $G_1$, $G_2$, . . . of k-regular graphs on vertex sets $V_1$, $V_2$, . . . is called a family of ε-vertex expanders if |$V_j$ | goes to infinity and for all sets S ⊂ Vj of at most half the vertices, we have |$N(S) \cup S$| ≥ (1 + ε)|$S$|.

So I have to show that any two vertices in $G_j$ are connected by a path of length at most c · log($n_j$ ) for ay graph in the family but I am not sure where to start. I am thinking of using eigenvalues as the max eigenvalue of k-regular graph is k. I'm not sure if lemma 4.22 in [http://home.iiserb.ac.in/~kashyap/Group/thesis_ashwin.pdf](http://home.iiserb.ac.in/%7Ekashyap/Group/thesis_ashwin.pdf) is similar to what i am trying to show here; that is the only close result i found. Any hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this question still open? If not, it is best to accept an answer to indicate this to others. Feel free to either accept mine or, even better, write up your own proof and accept that!

Comment: apologies, still reading through your answer so i upvoted it but didnt close it yet! i will close it as soon as i understand your full explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$
$\newcommand{\diam}{\operatorname{diam}}$

There is actually no need to work with a sequence of graphs here. It suffices to fix a single graph $G$ and establish the following result.

> Suppose that $G$ is an $\eps$-vertex expander, ie $|N(S) \cup S| \ge (1 + \eps) |S|$ with $|S| \le \tfrac12 |G|$. Then there exists a constant $c$, depending only on $\eps$, such that $\diam G \le c \log |G|$.

You missed the condition "$|S| \le \tfrac12 |G|$". This is crucial. Otherwise take $S := G$ and you get some set $N(G) \cup G$ of size larger than $|G|$!

Let's abbreviate $n := |G|$, as you have. We are going to define a sequence of nested sets $(B_k)_{k=0}^\infty$ and $(B'_k)_{k=0}^\infty$, each a subset of the vertex set of $G$.

- Fix an arbitrary $x \in G$ and set $B_0 := \{x\}$. In a rather obscure way of thinking about things, $B_0$ is the set of all vertices at distance at most $0$ from $x$.
- Now set $B_1 := N(\{x\}) \cup \{x\}$. This is the set of all vertices at distance at most $1$ from $x$, ie the neighbourhood of $x$ along with $x$ itself.
- The neighbourhood of the neighbourhood is all those at distance at most $2$. So set $B_2 := N(B_1) \cup B_1 = N^2(\{x\}) \cup N(\{x\}) \cup \{x\}$.
- Given $B_0, ..., B_{k-1}$, define $B_k := N(B_{k-1}) \cup B_{k-1}$.
- This way, $B_k$ is always the set of vertices at distance at most $k$ from $x$.

Similarly, fix an arbitrary $y \in G$ and define $(B'_k)_{k=0}^\infty$ analogously, but with respect to $y$. We want to find some $k$ so that $B_k \cap B'_k \ne \emptyset$. This means that there is a path from $x$ to $y$ of length at most $2k$.

Let's estimate the size of these sets. Suppose that $|B_{k-1}| \le \tfrac12 n$. Then our expander definition says that
$$
|B_k| \ge (1 + \eps) |B_{k-1}| \ge \cdots \ge (1 + \eps)^k.
$$
We always have $|B_k| \ge |B_{k-1}| + 1$ since $B_k \supsetneqq B_{k-1}$, unless $B_{k-1} = G$. Thus
$$
|B_k| \ge \min\{\tfrac12 n +1, (1 + \eps)^k \}.
$$
Now choose $k$ so that $(1 + \eps)^k \ge \tfrac23 n$; such a $k$ satisfies $k \le c \log n$ for some constant $c$ depending only on $\eps$. Now, for such a $k$, we have
$$
\min\{ |B_k|, |B'_k| \} > \tfrac12 n.
$$
Two sets taking up more than half of the vertices must intersect, ie $B_k \cap B'_k \ne \emptyset$. In particular, there is a path between $x$ and $y$ of length at most $2k \le 2 c \log n$. The proof is complete.